# How to convert `Date` to `Data`, and vice versa in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, swift5, nsdata, keychain

I'm trying to save a date in Keychain, and (from my understanding) this first requires converting the `Date` object into a `Data` object.

[This Stack Overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077198/swift3-date-to-data-data-to-date-convert) explains how to do it (or at least part of it) in Swift 3, but I'm hoping someone can provide the to/from functions in Swift 5 (since at least one of the methods in that solution are deprecated and I'm worried something else hasn't stood the test of time either).

Comment: Simple way: Since `Date` is just an object with highlever level method of a Timestamp (number of seconds since reference date 1970), just get that time timestamp( its a Double), and transform it into `Data`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data ?

Comment: @Larme I like it. Thank you.

Comment: @Eric check this post on how to properly convert a date to data and preserve its nanoseconds as well as its endianness. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502712/2303865

Comment: [A Date value encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date values represent a time interval relative to an absolute reference date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Date` is a juste a Timestamp (number of seconds since reference date of 1970 at UTC) as an object with fancy methods and other utilities. That's nothing more.

So based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/1801544) Double to Data (and reverse):

Input

```
let date = Date()
print(date)
```

Date -> Timestamp -> Data

```
let timestamp = date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
print(timestamp)
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: timestamp) { Data($0) }
print("\(data) - \(data.map{ String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())")
```

Data -> Timestamp -> Date

```
let retrievedTimestamp = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Double.self) }
print(retrievedTimestamp)
let retrievedDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: retrievedTimestamp)
print(retrievedDate)
```

Output:

```
$>2021-09-13 08:17:50 +0000
$>1631521070.6852288
$>8 bytes - cadaab4bc24fd841
$>1631521070.6852288
$>2021-09-13 08:17:50 +0000
```

Comment: Better to use timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate. If you use since 1970 there is no guarantee that if you convert it back to date it will be the exactly same date.

Comment: Isn't it the same? There is just "30 years" offset, no?

Comment: This won't be as precise as using `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`. Which is how it is stored under the hood. Check this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502712/2303865

Comment: [A Date value encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date values represent a time interval relative to an absolute reference date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date)

Answer (score 4):

A "safer" (but less efficient) way to do this would be to use an `Encoder`/`Decoder` type, such as `Foundation`s `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder`.
If the data gets corrupted in some way, these types will throw an `Error`, rather than trapping.
You just need to ensure that the date encoding/decoding strategy is the same for each.

```swift
let myDate = Date()

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970

// TODO: handle errors correctly
let dateData = try! encoder.encode(myDate)
let retrievedDate = try! decoder.decode(Date.self, from: dateData)

assert(myDate == retrievedDate)
```